# Can You Have Multiple Repos In One Project In Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

My project deployment is dependent on a third-party project that doesn't publish to maven central.

I would like to fork this project (from GitLab) into Azure DevOps then build and publish the jar into Azure Artifacts. I could then use this artifact in my main project.

However, Azure Artifacts seems to be at a project level and not at an organisation level.

It also looks to me like an Azure DevOps project is tied to only one repo.

Are these observations correct?

Is Azure Artifacts at a project level or at an organistation level?

Is it possible to have one project with 2 repos in it?

If I need 2 projects and the second publishes a jar to Azure Artifacts, can the first project access the jar?

Comment: You can create more then one repo in a project, so just fork the repo to your main project.

Comment: Its a badly written answer "No, you can". Is that "No you can't" or "Yes you can"? The part about how artifacts work isn't clear either. It suggests it is a maven repo specifically for that project that can be shared but doesn't explain how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure Artifacts is at organization level, you can access all artifacts from each team project. (but can't access it without a project)

To grant permission for each feed:

[image]

A project can has more than one repo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in another post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10886/how-to-have-multiple-git-repos-in-an-azure-devops-project), you can create multiple repositories in the same Azure DevOps project by following these steps:

1. Open your project and navigate to the `Repos`
2. In the breadcrumb at the top of the page, you should see the following navigation: `Organisation name` / `Project name` /Repos/Files/ `Repository name` (by default, the repository name is the same as the project's)
3. Click on the dropdown next to the repository name, this will allow you to:

   - Create a new repository
   - Import an existing repository
   - Manage existing repositories (rename/delete/change permissions)